# GTK+/ C++ gtk_label/ gtk_textview text sizing

Tags: c++, textview, gtk, spacing

[image: Example]

In the attached image on the left window I have the Ubuntu console with the content of the file and on the right window I have the content of the same file in my GTK+ program. The problem is that I want my GTK+ program to display the file exacly as it is displayed on my Ubuntu console.

I already tried displaying it by adding single line to single gtk_label and adding that label to vertical box, but the result was the same.

### Question

Is there any way I can make my gtk program have the same sizing/look the same as in the Ubuntu console?

### Here is the code:

```
void Zarzadzanie::Wykonaj(GtkWidget* widget, GtkWidget* data)
{
  string buffer;
  string n="";
  GtkWidget *dialog, *label, *vbox, *window2,*viewer;



  //Creating my dialog
  dialog=gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("Polaczenia sieciowe",GTK_WINDOW(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(data)), GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_STOCK_CLOSE, GTK_RESPONSE_CLOSE,GTK_STOCK_REFRESH,
                                           GTK_RESPONSE_OK, NULL );
  vbox=gtk_vbox_new(0,0); //creating new vbox
  window2=gtk_scrolled_window_new(0,0); //creating new scrolled window
  gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(gtk_dialog_get_widget_for_response(GTK_DIALOG(dialog),GTK_RESPONSE_CLOSE)),"Zamknij Okno"); //setting label in dialog
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_min_content_height(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(window2),400); //setting min height in scrollable window
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_min_content_width(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(window2),700); //setting min width in scrollable window


  viewer=gtk_text_view_new(); //creating new textview
  gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW (viewer), FALSE); //setting textview to not editable
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window2), viewer); //adding textview to scrollable window
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(dialog))),window2,0,0,0); //adding scrollable window to dialog


  ifstream plik("Pomniejsze/netstat.txt"); //reading from file
  if(plik==NULL) //checking if file is not empty
  {
      //i will add something later
  }
  else //if file is not empty
  {
      while(std::getline(plik, buffer)) //i read from file line by line
      {
          n+=buffer; //i add to "n" 1 line from file
          n+="\n"; //i add "new line" to "n" 
      }
      char* z=new char[n.length()+1]; //i create new temporary char*
      strcpy(z, n.c_str()); //i copy content of "n" to temporary char*
      gtk_text_buffer_set_text(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(viewer)),z,-1); //i set text of textview to text from temp char*
      g_print(z); //i print out temporary char* which can be seen on attached image on left window
      delete [] z; //i delete temporary char*

  }

  g_signal_connect(dialog, "delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), NULL); // i add delete event to "x" button
  gtk_widget_show_all(dialog); //i show my dialog
  gint resp=gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog)); //i run my dialog

  if(resp==GTK_RESPONSE_CLOSE) //i check if user clicked button
  {
     gtk_widget_destroy(dialog); //if button is clicked i destroy dialog
  }
  else if(resp==GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
  {
      //something will be added later
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a variable-width font. What you really want is a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), which is a fixed width, so all characters will line up from one row to another.

You can use [`gtk_text_view_set_monospace()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-set-monospace) to use only the default monospaced font. This function is only available since GTK+ version 3.16.

[Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Monospace) a list of common monospaced fonts. You can set the font to one of these using a [`PangoFontDescription`](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Fonts.html#pango-font-description-from-string) and [`gtk_widget_override_font()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-font). However, since this is deprecated and has been replaced with the `set_monospace()` function, you shouldn't need to manually force a certain monospace font.

Comment: Thanks, information about monospaced fonts helped me! gtk_text_view_set_monospace() gave me an error " error: 'gth_text_view_set_monospace' was not declared in this scope." But thanks to the information about font i used
PangoFontDescription *fon_desc;
fon_desc=pango_font_description_from_string("Courier New");
gtk_widget_override_font(viewer, fon_desc);
and it worked like a charm :) 
Thanks for help!

Comment: I just checked code, i seem to have mistyped the error message here, but in code it was
`gtk_text_view_set_monospace(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(viewer), TRUE);`

Comment: I use `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` to compile program, so it should be gtk+ 3. So I really don't know why i would get that error, but since `gtk_widget_override_font` worked for me it's not really a problem.

Comment: It seems that I use `Version: 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6` so it might be the reason why it didn't work. :)

Comment: Updated answer to include the version info and details on the manual method.